# Absolutely cannot reset my Moto G 2nd gen tracfone

Tags: motorola-moto-g

So I have had my phone sure Christmas and everything has been functioning properly. Now all of a sudden my phone has no bars anywhere I go, I cannot use the home button, notifications don't work, quick settings menu doesn't work, and my lock screen doesn't work.

After looking through multiple online threads I have decided to factory reset my phone, but one problem, my factory reset button is greyed out for some reason. When I try to hard reset my phone via the command prompt thing that, you can only get to by holding the buttons a certain way when it's starting, I go to "Factory" and it just starts up normally. Although if I go to recovery my phone shows an Android guy with a circle and a slash through its chest.
I have tried all 4 options I have under the command prompt thing with no avail.

I am running Android 6.0 if that helps.
Also my brother has the same exact phone and Android version but we can't figure out why his still works

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I have the EXACT same situation (had it since Christmas, had all the same issues you listed when I updated to Marshmallow, and my mom has the same phone and factory reset hers with no problem). I just did this so I'm not sure if it's just a quick fix, but I got my notifications and lock screen back (home button still doesn't work though).

Go into settings and click "users"
Switch to your guest user (if you don't have one set up, you can probably set it up) 
You should get any notifications that are for the whole phone (ie if there is WiFi available or if your storage is close to full; app notifications shouldn't come up)
Go back into settings>users and switch back to the owner account on the phone. 
Your lock screen should return, along with any notifications you missed. The drop down settings menu is accessible as well.

Like I said, the home button is still unresponsive for me, and I'm not sure if this is a long term solution, but at least it's something!